# Excel VBA - when subtracting two dates VBA sees them as numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I use Excel 2013.
When I subtract two dates in excel "1.11.2019" and "1.10.2019" I get the result 31 as you should.
But when I do the same thing in VBA I get 10000. So it sees them as regular numbers "1112019" and "1102019". How can I get the same result in VBA too?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post your code? Are you using Date type variables?

Comment: If you have real dates in Excel, the subtraction works correctly. But if you have strings that look like a date (for your eyes), and ask Excel to do calculations with it, you force Excel to guess what the content is - and that is highly dependent on language and number format settings of your computer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateDiff()` function with `d` interval to get days difference between two date. Try like below.

```
Sub DateSubstract()
    MsgBox DateDiff("d", Range("B1"), Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may have to format the string into a Date format

```
Dim diff As Long
Dim strDate1, strDate2 As String
Dim fDate1, FDate2 As Date
 
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("myDate")
' convert in string with 8 caracters
strDate1 = Right("0" & sh.Range("A1").Value, 8)
strDate2 = Right("0" & sh.Range("B1").Value, 8)
'format Year, month, day
fDate1 = DateSerial(Right(strDate1, 4), Mid(strDate1, 3, 2), Left(strDate1, 2))
fDate2 = DateSerial(Right(strDate2, 4), Mid(strDate2, 3, 2), Left(strDate2, 2))

diff = DateDiff("d", fDate2, fDate1)
Debug.Print ("difference :" & diff)
```